# Работа с картой в Android

Tags: android

Возникла необходимость из приложения получить доступ к картам. Сам по себе этот вопрос не сложен и подробно описан, но далее необходимо вернуть в приложение данные об отмеченной на карте точке (название, координаты) и вот тут возникли сложности, ни какой информации по этому вопросу я не нашел. Если кто-то уже успешно решал подобную проблему, буду очень признателен за помощь.

Comment: Вы работаете с Google Maps или Яндекс Картами? Вопрос очень расплывчатый. Или же нужно сначала получить координаты устройства, а позже на основе координат получить адрес?

Comment: Постараюсь конкретизировать вопрос. В приложении типа "планировщик" можно указывать место где запланировано событие, для этого пользователю предоставляется доступ к карте где он отмечает нужное место. В приложении нужно сохранить название этого места и его координаты. Вопрос в том каким образом решается эта задача?